# python iterate through list by string matching

Tags: python

I have a list of strings and if the string in my list appears in the filename then I want python to open the file. The catch is, I want python to open the files in the order the string appears in my list. My current code opens the files in the order python wants and only checks if the string in the list appears in the filename.

files

```
dogs.html
cats.html
fish.html
```

python

```
list = ['fi', 'do', 'ca']
for name in glob.glob('*.html'):
  for item in list:
    if item in name:
      with open(name) as k:
```

Comment: So iterate over you list of strings instead of over the files.

Comment: Would you want `catfish.html` to be opened once or twice?

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lis = ['fi', 'do', 'ca']

for item in lis:
   for name in glob.glob('*.html'):
      if item in name:
         with open(name) as k:
```

or create a list of all files first, and then filter that list with every iteration of `list`:

```
>>> names=glob.glob('*.html')
>>> lis=['fi','do','ca']
>>> for item in lis:
...    for name in filter(lambda x:item in x,names):
...         with open('name') as k:
```

Comment: That's a lot of redundant file-system access.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I agree, but I wanted to improve the OP's version.

Comment: The OP's version only does one directory listing.

Comment: You can easily move the glob outside the loop and do `for name in globresult` to remove excess globs

Comment: `glob.glob()` already returns a list. The list comprehension is redundant redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a set of matches:

```
matching_glob = set([name for name in glob.glob('*.html')])
```

and then filter your list

```
list_matching_glob = filter (lambda el: el in matching_glob) filter
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a bit simpler by repeating the glob calls:

```
names = ['fi', 'do', 'ca']
patterns = [s + "*.html" for s in names]

for pattern in patterns:
    for fn in glob.glob(pattern):
        with open(name) as k:
            pass
```

You can factor out the repeated file system access by using os.listdir and glob.fnmatch, in case you process thousands of files.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
filenames = glob.glob('*.html')

for my_string in my_strings:
    for fname in (filename for filename in filenames if my_string in filename):
        with open(fname) as fobj:
            #do something.
```